# Button values in single textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").on('click', function() {
        var caretPos = document.getElementById("txt").selectionStart;
        var textAreaTxt = $("#txt").val();
        var txtToAdd = $("#btn").val();
        $("#txt").val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
    })
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="70"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="OK" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Bye" />
<input type="button" id="btn" value="TC" />
```

I want to give these values in textarea. But it is only giving value of Ok button. How I can give each button values in textarea

Comment: why same id for all buttons ?

Comment: then what can I do to show every button value with same script

Comment: @Elixir you need to use classes for that. Having duplicate `id` within a page is invalid.

Comment: use class instead of id,or give different id for each button and in javascript take values of button and append to textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this 
**html**

```
<textarea id="txt" rows="15" cols="70"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="OK" />
   <input type="button" id="btn" value="Bye" />
   <input type="button" id="btn" value="TC" />
```

**javascript**

```
 $('input#btn').click(function() 
    { 
       $('#txt').val($('#txt').val()+this.value); // append the value of each button
    })
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/8f8f17bz/)

Comment: And when I click Ok Bye and TC button . After that I move my cursor in front of Ok button and click Bye button then bye button value should be at First position and all values OK Bye TC should remain at previous postion

Comment: @Elixir if you want something like that have to derive logic for that , i think you can use the logic of 3 clicks. I mean after three click then when the forth click is came that time take the button name and then replace it with first string in textarea when 5 th click occurs replace it with second text like wise

Comment: no if add 7 buttons then what would happen. I want it for each and every button.

Comment: @Elixir i think there is no inbuilt method for doing this , we must write our own logic for this , if you know the number of buttons then you can use this same logic

Answer (score 4):

You have the same id on elements. ID's must be unique. You can use `class` and end to this:

```js
$(".btn").on('click', function() {
  $("#txt").val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="txt" rows="5" cols="10"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="btn" value="OK" />
<input type="button" class="btn" value="Bye" />
<input type="button" class="btn" value="TC" />
```

Comment: This code is replacing each value but I need each button value in textarea on click according to the cursor's postion

Comment: @Elixir you want to keep and the previous value?

Answer (score 1):

```
<textarea name="insert" rows="5" cols="30" id="insert" onblur="myFunction()"></textarea>
<button class="myvalue" id="myvalue">Ok</button>
    <button class="myvalue" id="myvalue">Bye</button>
    <button class="myvalue" id="myvalue">Tc</button>
<script>
function insertAt (myField, myValue, startSel, endSel)
 {
if (startSel || startSel == '0') {
    var startPos = startSel;

    var endPos = endSel;

    myField.val(myField.val().substring(0, startPos)+ myValue+ myField.val().substring(endPos, myField.val().length));

  }`  else {
  myField.val() += myValue;
  }`}var targetBox = $('textarea#insert'),
startSel, 
endSel;`targetBox.bind('focusout', function() {
startSel = this.selectionStart;
endSel = this.selectionEnd;
});

$(".myvalue").click(function() {
    var myValue = $(this).text();
    insertAt(targetBox, myValue, startSel, endSel);

});    
</script>
```

Finally It Works

Answer (score 0):

> My suggestion to you change button `id` to `class` because `id` is unique for each element so you have to use `class` instead of `id`.

```
$("input.btn").on('click', function() {
    $("#txt").val($("#txt").val()+$(this).val());
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n7netc32/2/)**

Comment: Before your thinking you just confirm with OP.

Comment: first of all i did't downvote for your post, i had seen the output in fiddle, it shows ok when clicks ok button and bye when clicking bye button likewise.. but i think questioner want to show ok,bye,tc in each button click. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @Elixir you mean append each button value to textarea when clicks, i mean first it shows ok then if we clicks bye then it shows ok bye likewise am i right ?

Comment: Your quote says to change `id` to `class` yet your code is still using the `id`.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated my answer with `class` insteadOf `id` check it.

Comment: And when I click Ok Bye and TC button . After that I move my cursor in front of Ok button and click Bye button then bye button value should be at First position and all values OK Bye TC should remain at previous postion

Answer (score 0):

All your buttons have the same 'id', and 'OK' is the first one, so that's the one that's being returned...

To get the value of the button that's clicked you'd need to give each one a unique id (which should be the case anyway).

I would put your buttons in a separate container, probably a div, and apply the click handler to that. In the handler function, see if the event target has a value attribute, and if it has, send it to your textbox.

Or you could give each button a handler, it depends on your circumstances...

Danny